# How to rename standard 'More' tab in UITabBarController with more than 5 custom view controllers

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, swift2, tabbar

Swift 2.0
I have UITabBarController with more than 5 custom view controllers. In this case the tab bar controller displays only the first four items plus the standard 'More' item on the tab bar.
How I can rename this 'More' tab? 
My client want to see another word instead 'More' (for example, 'Extra').
Thanks advance!

Comment: I tried in viewDidLoad:
moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = "Extra" (doesn't work).
And: 
moreNavigationController.tabBarItem.title = "Extra" (doesn't work)

Comment: If you add more than five items to the viewControllers property, the tab bar controller automatically inserts a special view controller (called the More view controller) to handle the display of the additional items. The More view controller provides a custom interface that lists the additional view controllers in a table. The More view controller cannot be customized or selected and does not appear in any of the view controller lists managed by the tab bar controller. For the most part, it appears automatically when it is needed and is separate from your custom content.